# "backspace" a character

Tags: macros, strings

It's not really "backspace" a character: I define a command, for example `\foo` representing *bar*, actually a macro for replacement. I need to produce the string *bars* with `\foo`. It's impossible to just use `\foos`, so there must be whitespace between `\foo` and **s**. That's why I wish to backspace the whitespace. What's the solution?

Comment: `\newcommand*{\foo}{bar}` plus `\foo's` results in `bar's` for me.

Comment: Why should it be impossible to use `\foo's`? The control sequence name is stopped by the nonletter `'`. On the other hand, `\foo 's` would work the same and *not* produce white space.

Comment: Yes, you are right---my mistake. I want **\foo\foo\foo**.

Comment: `\foo\foo\foo` produces `barbarbar`.

Comment: My stupid: It's a problem days ago, and I cannot remember exactly. I checked and it should be **bars**. Sorry, man.

Comment: @Kejia柯嘉: Even for that the same holds. The space after `\foo` is gobbled as a macro termination, leaving no space between `bar` and `s`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand, so are you just looking for a simple replacement such as this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\foo}{bar}%

\begin{document}
\foo's
\end{document}
```

With the above using `\foo's` produces **bar's** for me.

If you have issues with terminating a macro the way to do that is `\foo{}'s`, but in this case it does not seem necessary.  Where it would be necessary is if you wanted to produce **bars**, then you would use `\foo{}s`.

Comment: @Peter: even in `\foo{}s`, braces are unnecessary: `\foo s` works well: the space after `\foo` is simply ignored by TeX. Then choosing between `\foo{}s` and `\foo s` is a matter of taste.

Comment: @BrunoLeFloch: Good point. I have gotten into the habit of using `\foo{}s` style, so `\foo s` did not even come to mind. Good to know there are options.